# headMeta - appendName or appendHttpEquiv

Tags: php, zend-framework

What's the difference between the appendName() and appendHttpEquiv() methods of headMeta()? As an example, is `keywords` meant to be used with Name or http-equiv?

```
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('keywords', 'keys');
or 
$view->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', 'keys');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is

```
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('keywords', 'keys');
```

creates

```
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keys" >
```

while

```
$view->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', 'keys');
```

creates

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keys" >
```

[According to the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4.2)

> http-equiv may be used in place of the name attribute. HTTP servers use this attribute to gather information for HTTP response message headers.

The [XHTML2.0 specs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html) are a bit more descriptive on this:

> `HTTP-EQUIV`
>    binds the element to an HTTP header field. An HTTP server may use this information to process the document. In particular, it may include a header field in the responses to requests for this document: the header name is taken from the HTTP-EQUIV attribute value, and the header value is taken from the value of the CONTENT attribute. HTTP header names are not case sensitive.
>
> `NAME`
>   specifies the name of the name/value pair. If not present, HTTP-EQUIV gives the name.

Since you are unlikely sending the keywords in the header, using name is the proper way.

Comment: Is there a reference somewhere to help me decide whether to use name or http-equiv for each attribute? I'm wondering about Content-Type, set-cookie, Cache-Control and more, so a reference list would definitely help.

Comment: @jblue [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) lists [metatags.org](http://www.metatags.org/all_metatags)